# Microsoft Access query seen as a Function or View by Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, dataset

I have a **Microsoft Access** database query that I'm trying to import into a **Visual Studio 2005** dataset.

When the query is formed using an **NZ()** function like this:

```
SELECT NZ(tblComponentSpecs.nPurchaseCostQuantity, 0) AS Quantity
FROM tblComponentSpecs;
```

it appears under the **Functions** list in the Data Connection.

However, when the query is formed using an **IIF()** function like this:

```
SELECT IIF(tblComponentSpecs.nPurchaseCostQuantity Is Null, 0, nPurchaseCostQuantity) AS Quantity
FROM tblComponentSpecs;
```

it appears under the **Views** list.

Can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is because `Nz()` is a VBA function, whereas `IIF` is part of Jet SQL. (Yes, there also is a function named `Iif()` in VBA. Further info is on [Allen Browne's web site](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html).)

I guess that `IIF` is translated to `CASE WHEN` and then makes a valid view, and `Nz()` is not translated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's probably it. Allen Browne's site is excellent too. Cheers.